# About adjective order

Tags: word-order

my editor just revised the adjective order in a sentence of my article. But it seems that the original order was right and there was no need to change it? The rule of thumb is that an adjective describing an opinion should be placed before one describing a nature? Reference: https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/order_of_adjectives.htm

Below please see the change he made:

**Original sentence:**
Working on commission, the masters naturally gave **pleasant selective** foresights.

**Revised version:**
Working on commission, the masters naturally gave **selective pleasant** foresights.

Comment: I agree with the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider what is being modified.  Pleasant is modifying insights.  This they must stay connected. The choice of the insights was selective, but it doesn’t modify insights.  So selective describes the “pleasant insights”.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. It is very helpful!